# Probability of eventual success in independent trials (close form expression)

Tags: geometric-probability

Consider a sequence of independent trials with success probability $p$.
The formula for eventual success, i.e., there will be at least one success eventually, is 
$$ q = 1 - \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}{1-p(1-p)^{n-1}} $$

Is there a closed form expression for the above formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p\ne 0$. The probability of **no** success in $n$ trials is $(1-p)^n$. This has limit $0$ as $n\to\infty$. So the probability of at least one success "eventually" is $1$.

Comment: Of course, thanks!. The mistake I made in coming up with the above formula is assuming that the following events 1) "probability of no success in exactly $k$ trials" and 2) "probability of no success in exactly $k+1$ trials" , are independent. But, they are not.

Comment: You are welcome. It is the monkeys and Shakespeare thing: A monkey typing at random will (with probability $1$) eventually write Hamlet.